# objectify java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, objectify

I am a newbie to objectify so I know a goofed something up but I have defined the service as they describe in Best Practices

```
package com.hmt1.objectify;

import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory;
import com.googlecode.objectify.Objectify;
import com.hmt1.entities.User;
import com.hmt1.entities.Match;

public class OfyService {
static {
 factory().register(User.class);
 factory().register(Match.class);
 // factory().register(OtherThing.class);

}

public static Objectify ofy() {
    return ObjectifyService.ofy();
}

public static ObjectifyFactory factory() {
    return ObjectifyService.factory();
}
}
```

I think I have the static import correct ?

```
import static com.hmt1.objectify.OfyService.ofy;

public class UserOperations {

public boolean isEmailInUse(String email) {

     try {

        User user =  ofy().load().type(User.class).filter("email", email).first().get();
        if (user == null )
             return false;
         else
             return   true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("email in use  exception");
        return false;
    }

}
```

When I run I get the  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at the ofy() line.
What did I forget to do?

here is the enum now

```
package com.hmt1.entities;

import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Embed;
 import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;

 @Embed
 public enum countryCode {US,CANADA,MEXICO;
  countryCode(){

 }
 }
```

Here is the stack trace

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.hmt1.objectify.UserOperations.isEmailInUse(UserOperations.java:66)
    at com.hmt1.datahandling.SignupPageDataHandling.isemailInUse(SignupPageDataHandling.java:15)
    at com.hmt1.controller.SignupController.selection(SignupController.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:59)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:383)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to construct an instance of com.hmt1.entities.countryCode; perhaps it has no suitable constructor?
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslator.<init>(ClassTranslator.java:44)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.EmbedClassTranslatorFactory.create(EmbedClassTranslatorFactory.java:43)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.TranslatorRegistry.create(TranslatorRegistry.java:91)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslator.<init>(ClassTranslator.java:49)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.EntityClassTranslator.<init>(EntityClassTranslator.java:46)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Transmog.<init>(Transmog.java:49)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ConcreteEntityMetadata.<init>(ConcreteEntityMetadata.java:58)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Registrar.register(Registrar.java:74)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory.register(ObjectifyFactory.java:177)
    at com.hmt1.objectify.OfyService.<clinit>(OfyService.java:11)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.hmt1.entities.countryCode must have a no-arg constructor
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.TypeUtils.getNoArgConstructor(TypeUtils.java:52)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory.construct(ObjectifyFactory.java:78)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslator.<init>(ClassTranslator.java:42)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.hmt1.entities.countryCode.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2715)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1987)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.TypeUtils.getNoArgConstructor(TypeUtils.java:43)
    ... 68 more
```

Comment: It would be too interesting to learn what the exception was that happened in some initializer.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: The full stack trace (unless your IDE has "helpfully" concealed if from you) should identify the specific exception that occurred.  You need to look at that to see what caused the exception.

Comment: Thanks you pointed me in the right direction Searching through the stack I found :
java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.hmt1.entities.countryCode must have a no-arg constructor

Comment: In objectify do I need to have constructors for enums?  I have tried just a blank no-arg constructor and it doesn't like that either

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.hmt1.entities.countryCode must have a no-arg constructor
 at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.TypeUtils.getNoArgConstructor(TypeUtils.java:52)
 at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFactory.construct(ObjectifyFactory.java:78)
 at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.ClassTranslator.<init>(ClassTranslator.java:42)
 ... 66 more

Comment: You didn't look far enough: `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.hmt1.entities.countryCode.() at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2715)...`  You have a version problem with the jar containing `com.html.entities.countryCode`.

Comment: (Though a method named `()` seems suspicious.)

Comment: the countryCode(){} constructor was the last thing I did to try to fix the problem.  As far as jars, countryCode is just in the eclipse project with the rest of the code that uses it. Not sure what would have the version problem

Comment: @HotLicks: the method named `()` was just an artifact of the stacktrace not being formatted as code.  Markdown removed the `<init>` bit, thinking it might be an HTML tag.

Comment: @LukeWoodward - Yeah, that makes more sense.

Comment: No such method exception is usually due to compiling against one version and running against a different version.

Comment: I am just building and compiling and running the app engine locally. this all started when I changed from this line to my local objectify service   import static com.hmt1.objectify.OfyService.ofy;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe enums need to have the @Embed notation.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You only put @Embed on real classes with fields that you need to embed. Enums just work as-is.

Comment: It only took me all day to figure it out - AAAAHH!